# Same post appears in related Posts?

Tags: posts, functions, wp-query

Here is the code

```
function dark_delight_get_related_posts(){
    $post = get_post();

    $args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => 4,
            'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
            'posts__not_in' => array($post->ID),
            );

    $categories = get_the_category();
    if( !empty($categories) ){
        $category = array_shift( $categories );
        $args['tax_query'] = array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => $category->term_id,
                ),
            );
    }

    return new WP_Query( $args );
}
```

I opened 'Hello world!' post and it shows up in the Related posts too.

Comment: What is the ID of "Hello World" post? Add `var_dump($post->ID);` just after `$post = get_post();`. What will it output?

Comment: It shows int(1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aahhh, it's a typo, I guess.

There is no parameter called `posts__not_in`. It's called `post__not_in`.

So you should change your code to:

```
function dark_delight_get_related_posts(){
    $post = get_post();

    $args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => 4,
            'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
            'post__not_in' => array($post->ID), // post and not posts
            );

    $categories = get_the_category();
    if( !empty($categories) ){
        $category = array_shift( $categories );
        $args['tax_query'] = array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => $category->term_id,
                ),
            );
    }

    return new WP_Query( $args );
}
```